# Using twin WAN Router with one Static IP and one Dynamic IP Internet connection

Tags: router, wide-area-network

I have a high speed Internet connection with dynamic IP that we use in our office. We have some services like, svn, that we want our clients to access. So we checked with our ISP to provide static IP on our current high speed plan. But this is costing way too much. So we have thought to buy another low speed connection with a static IP.

Sometimes we our clients have firewalled server and to access (FTP etc) them we have to provide our IP. But since it is dynamic client has to update it everytime it is changed. So to solve that also we need a static IP.

So I wanted to know if we buy a twin wan router, will it solve our need to provide access to our clients to some services as well as continue using the high speed connection for our daily use?

Which Twin WAN router you would suggest for the purpose?
Or is there a better cost effective setup we can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the new connection with static IP will be needed just for **incoming** connections, you can easily just put another router configured accordingly and get away with it. Your office will continue to use current *high speed* connection, and your clients
will access the services through the new IP.

Different matter if you'll want to load-balance/automatic-failover your connections, too.